# Magmi - Cleared Catalog/Categories - Sqlstate Invalid Parameter on Import

Tags: magento, magmi

I have been using magmi to import products and related categories / images into magento.

Everything was setup and working correctly. I cleared Magento catalog and categories using the Magmi advanced utility and now on import i receive the following error message:

SQLSTATE[HY093]: Invalid parameter number: no parameters were bound - ERROR ON RECORD #1

etc, etc for each record.

I noticed that before i cleared the catalog/categories, with a fresh magento install i had only one category labeled "Default Category".

After the catalog/categories were cleared; The structure starts with the category "Root Catalog" with "Default Category" as a sub directory.

I deleted these categories and re-created the Default Category but it did not solve the issue most likely due to the category ID not matching?

Anyone ever come across this issue? Im not too sure how to go about solving this if anyone may have some input on this matter!

Comment: Can you post a few lines of your import file.

Comment: Cannot post comment. Just the Header row and one product row i am over by 1200 char (with desc, title etc replaced with single word) I am using the same unmodified import file before and after i used the utility.

Answer (score 1):

This is probably due to a bug/error in the Magmi Clean Catalog utility. I did encounter the same error (Magento 1.8) however I was only able to it solve by Truncating the products / categories tables. To do this just run the script below. Not a very elegant solution....but it did the job.

SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS = 0;
TRUNCATE TABLE `catalog_product_bundle_option`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `catalog_product_bundle_option_value`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `catalog_product_bundle_selection`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `catalog_product_entity_datetime`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `catalog_product_entity_decimal`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `catalog_product_entity_gallery`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `catalog_product_entity_int`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `catalog_product_entity_media_gallery`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `catalog_product_entity_media_gallery_value`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `catalog_product_entity_text`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `catalog_product_entity_tier_price`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `catalog_product_entity_varchar`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `catalog_product_link`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `catalog_product_link_attribute`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `catalog_product_link_attribute_decimal`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `catalog_product_link_attribute_int`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `catalog_product_link_attribute_varchar`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `catalog_product_link_type`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `catalog_product_option`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `catalog_product_option_price`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `catalog_product_option_title`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `catalog_product_option_type_price`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `catalog_product_option_type_title`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `catalog_product_option_type_value`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `catalog_product_super_attribute`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `catalog_product_super_attribute_label`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `catalog_product_super_attribute_pricing`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `catalog_product_super_link`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `catalog_product_enabled_index`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `catalog_product_website`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `catalog_product_entity`;

TRUNCATE TABLE `cataloginventory_stock`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `cataloginventory_stock_item`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `cataloginventory_stock_status`;

TRUNCATE TABLE `catalog_category_entity`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `catalog_category_entity_datetime`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `catalog_category_entity_decimal`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `catalog_category_entity_int`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `catalog_category_entity_text`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `catalog_category_entity_varchar`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `catalog_category_product`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `catalog_category_product_index`;

INSERT INTO `catalog_category_entity` (`entity_id`, `entity_type_id`, `attribute_set_id`, `parent_id`, `created_at`, `updated_at`, `path`, `position`, `level`, `children_count`) VALUES (1, 3, 0, 0, '2012-06-17 22:20:47', '2012-06-17 22:20:47', '1', 0, 0, 1), (2, 3, 3, 1, '2012-06-17 22:20:47', '2012-06-17 22:20:47', '1/2', 1, 1, 0);
INSERT INTO `catalog_category_entity_int` (`value_id`, `entity_type_id`, `attribute_id`, `store_id`, `entity_id`, `value`) VALUES (1, 3, 67, 0, 1, 1), (2, 3, 67, 1, 1, 1), (3, 3, 42, 0, 2, 1), (4, 3, 67, 0, 2, 1), (5, 3, 42, 1, 2, 1), (6, 3, 67, 1, 2, 1);
INSERT INTO `catalog_category_entity_varchar` (`value_id`, `entity_type_id`, `attribute_id`, `store_id`, `entity_id`, `value`) VALUES (1, 3, 41, 0, 1, 'Root Catalog'), (2, 3, 41, 1, 1, 'Root Catalog'), (3, 3, 43, 1, 1, 'root-catalog'), (4, 3, 41, 0, 2, 'Default Category'), (5, 3, 41, 1, 2, 'Default Category'), (6, 3, 49, 1, 2, 'PRODUCTS'), (7, 3, 43, 1, 2, 'default-category');

INSERT INTO `catalog_product_link_type` (`link_type_id`, `code`) VALUES (1, 'relation'), (3, 'super'), (4, 'up_sell'), (5, 'cross_sell');
INSERT INTO `catalog_product_link_attribute` (`product_link_attribute_id`, `link_type_id`, `product_link_attribute_code`, `data_type`) VALUES (1, 1, 'position', 'int'), (2, 3, 'position', 'int'), (3, 3, 'qty', 'decimal'), (4, 4, 'position', 'int'), (5, 5, 'position', 'int');
INSERT INTO `cataloginventory_stock` (`stock_id`, `stock_name`) VALUES (1, 'Default');

SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS = 1;